# How to check for Shader Model 3.0 Support?

Tags: delphi, 3d, delphi-xe

Currently i am working on a 3d visualization app , requirement of my app is that host's graphic-card does support `Shader Model 3.0`

do you know any work around checking Shader Model 3.0 Support via delphi

**Just for more information**
I know this

```
• DirectX 8.0 - Shader Model 1.0 & 1.1
• DirectX 8.0a - Shader Model 1.3
• DirectX 8.1 - Shader Model 1.4
• DirectX 9.0 - Shader Model 2.0
• DirectX 9.0a - Shader Model 2.0a
• DirectX 9.0b - Shader Model 2.0b
• DirectX 9.0c - Shader Model 3.0
• DirectX 10.0* - Shader Model 4.0
• DirectX 10.1* - Shader Model 4.1
• DirectX 11.0* - Shader Model 5.0
```

BUT some graphic hardware doesn't support shader model 3.0 ( even with installing proper directx ) , the thing is i want to determine it by checking the hardware

Thanks in advance

**EDIT : OK I did figure it out**( Thanks to people on [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22705/how-can-i-check-for-shader-model-3-support) )

Using GPU-Z , Command line

```
gpu-z.exe -dump gpuz.xml
```

Comment: What graphics API and operating system are you on? Given those, you may receive a better answer.

Comment: @josephthomas Windows XP SP3 & Win 7 , GDI Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GPU-Z , Command line

```
gpu-z.exe -dump gpuz.xml
```